# Why can I not see my own question, which was probably deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked [Is there a book about the "War on General Computation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791131/is-there-a-book-about-the-war-on-general-computation) My Inbox tells me that someone left a comment:

> Relevance to the community does not make a […]

I assume, the full comment was about to tell me that the question does not belong on Stack Overflow. I also assume, that some 10K user deleted the question for the same reason.

I understand that 10K users can delete questions, and I can guess their rationale, but why is it impossible to read the comment they left for me? Also, when trying to access the question, why does SO return "Page Not Found" (as if a technical error had occurred) instead of "Question was deleted"? (I'm logged in and I'm the OP. I'm not a guest, or a search engine.)

Comment: [The ability to view your own deleted posts has been requested many times and rejected.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645) :( Stack Exchange often returns 404 for content users aren't allowed to see as a form of security through obscurity, though that wouldn't really apply in this case. The full comment from [Oded](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) was "Relevance to the community does not make a question (or topic) immediately on-topic here. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Asking for book recommendations is always off-topic.".

Comment: Well, actually [that URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791131/is-there-a-book-about-the-war-on-general-computation) tells you [in yellow highlighting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5YWP.png) that the question was deleted, and links to the FAQ for more generic information!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question got *closed* by 5 close votes as off-topic.

It was the deleted by 3 delete votes.

A single 10k user can't close or delete questions by himself (moderators excluded).

The comment (which was simply voluntary) was:

> Relevance to the community does not make a question (or topic) immediately on-topic here. Please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Asking for book recommendations is always off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

> why does SO return "Page Not Found" (as if a technical error had occured) instead of "Question was deleted"?

Actually, using the 404 error when the user is not allowed to see the page is contemplated in the [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4):

> #### **10.4.4 403 Forbidden**
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>      Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
>      If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
>      public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
>      reason for the refusal in the entity. **If the server does not wish to
>      make this information available to the client, the status code 404
>      (Not Found) can be used instead**.